# Deleting multiple observation from access with sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, dataframe

I have an access database and I want to delete literally thousands of individual observations from a database of millions. My issue is this: I know how to write the where statement to delete individual observations where there attribute is equal to what i want to delete, but in this case, i have thousands of different numbers within that variable. Ex below

```
   city      state    license number
  Cleveland   oh         648758
    etc       etc          etc
     .          .           .
     .          .           .
     .          .           .
     .          .           .
```

IN my situation i want to delete thousands of observations based on licence number but as you can imagine they are all different. I do not want to have to put commas in-between all the numbers that i want to delete.

my overall question is, can i pass sql a vector that  i already know so access sees each number as different within the vector

Comment: Can you write a query to get all records you wish to delete?

Comment: Can you define rules which defines a set of data containing all the license numbers you want to delete?  `DELETE FROM Tbl where license_number in (Select license_number from tbl2 where col2='somevalue' and col3='someotherval')`

Comment: Before anything else - make at least one backup.
If there are thousands of variations it may just be simpler (and more efficient) to do the delete operations 1 at a time (or smaller groups at least - thousands of parameters as a WHERE IN may be very slow), either using a simple access form with vba or some other client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import your list of license numbers to be deleted into a separate table, and join that table to your main table in the DELETE statement, e.g.:

```
delete distinctrow main_table.*
from
    main_table
    inner join delete_list on delete_list.license_number = main_table.license_number;
```

Comment: @rd_nielson I followed those instructions and it said could not delete from specified tables

Comment: @Washingtonstateone: Apologies; it was missing a `distinctrow` specification.  I've edited the SQL; see if that works.